# Designing proper relations for tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm designing a simple db (still learning)

Here's the entities

User, Topic, Article

User Topic is many to many(a user can be interested in many topics)
Topic User is many to many(a topic can be interested by many users)
User Blog is one to many (a user can write many blogs)
Blog User is one to one (a blog can be authored only by one user)

here's the question:
Shall I still make a one to many relationship between Topic and Blogs?

For instance, if I want to find all the latest blogs for certain topics, one way is to find all the users, and find all the blogs for those users, rank by time.

Another way is, if we keep redundancy by having a Topic to Blog relationship (one to many), then we can get all the blogs from the topic directly, then sort by time.

I'm kind confused, shall I have this redundancy? whats's the best practice here (in terms of ease of programming for backend programmers and query efficiencies? est users 100k, blogs 200k, Topics 20)

Thanks a lot!

Add a pic:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

For many to many relationships you should use [associative entity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity) which means adding a bridge table to store relations, and for one to many simply store the relation key as a foreign key constraint.

Saying that your schema could look like:

- Users
- Topic
- Users_Topic (where primary key would consist of columns identifying both Users and Topic)
- Article (where it has a foreign key to table Users through a column eg. user_id)

---

Regarding Article and Topic relation, there's no need for redundancy by storing it in a separate table, so you could include a foreign key to topic within an article. If you are worried about querying Article table that much, which I don't think should be your consideration right now you can create a table which stores Article content since it is what takes space within the table and call it Article_Content with foreign key to Article also being the primary key for this new table.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Kamil

Comment: actually im doing that via UserTopic table (many to many relation). but the question is really about shall I keep the Topic to Blog relation.

Comment: Updated my answer to include some additional information regarding articles and topics.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the update! I understand now that Article will have a foreign key pointing to User. However do I still need a relation between article and topic? If yes is that redundancy introduced?

Comment: Added a picture for clarity :)

Comment: You should have this and it doesn't introduce redudancy, since this relation is different from `Article-Users-Users_Community`. An article is written within a community and it doesn't equal the information of it being written by an user who subscribes/belongs to many communities.